# $\kappa$-free abelian groups and inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, free-modules, free-abelian-group

I found the following unproved statements in Shelah and Mekler's article "On the consistency strength of "every stationary set reflects"".

> Let $\kappa$ be the least cardinal such that there exists a $\kappa$-free abelian group which is not $\kappa^+$-free. By a well known
>   argument, $\kappa$ is either the successor of a singular cardinal or an inaccessible
>   cardinal.
>
> It is easy to see (and well known) that if every stationary set
>   reflects in a regular cardinal then every $\kappa$-free abelian group is
>   $\kappa^+$-free.

Can someone please give references for the above statements? In particulary I am deeply interested in the first one, but I couldn't find any introductory material. The wonderful book "Almost free modules" by Paul Eklof strangely doesn't mention the result (or I couldn't find it!).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper

> [MR1029909 (91b:03090)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1029909). Mekler, Alan H.; Shelah, Saharon. *[The consistency strength of "every stationary set reflects"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02764953)*. Israel J. Math. **67** (1989), no. 3, 353–366,

that you mention in the question actually provides the relevant references and explains the key idea of the argument. Note first that $\kappa$ is assumed regular.

They refer to

> [MR0379694 (52 #599)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=379694). Eklof, Paul C. *[On the existence of $\kappa$-free abelian groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-047-01/S0002-9939-1975-0379694-0/S0002-9939-1975-0379694-0.pdf)*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **47** (1975), 65–72.

In that paper, Eklof essentially shows that if $\kappa$ is regular and there is a stationary subset of $\kappa$ that does not reflect, then there is a $\kappa$-free not $\kappa^+$-free abelian group. This means that if we want the opposite, every stationary subset of $\kappa$ must reflect.

The point then is to note that $S^{\tau^+}_\tau$ is non-reflecting whenever $\tau$ is regular. Here $S^{\tau^+}_\tau$ is the set of ordinals smaller than $\tau^+$ of cofinality $\tau$. To see this, let $\alpha\in S^{\tau^+}_\tau$, fix a club subset $C$ of $\alpha$ of type $\tau$, and note that $C'$ cannot meet $S^{\tau^+}_\tau$ since no point of $C'$ has cofinality $\tau$.

This leaves us with $\kappa$ being inaccessible or the successor of a singular, since all other regular cardinals are of the form $\kappa^+$ for $\kappa$ regular.

Comment: Thank you very much. By "inaccessible" one means "weakly inaccessible", so?

Comment: In this context, yes. What Mekler and Shelah prove is that if $\kappa $ is regular and every stationary set reflects (in $V $), then $\kappa $ is greatly Mahlo and limit of greatly Mahlo cardinals in $L $. The precise large cardinal notion they identify they call a reflecting cardinal. Curiously, the case where $\kappa $ is the successor of a singular cardinal is significantly larger in consistency strength.

Comment: Just one more question: in your answer you prove that if the implication "$\kappa$-free$\Longrightarrow\kappa^+$-free" holds then $\kappa$ is not the successor of a regular cardinal. Now, if I take the least one such that the opposite is true, it appears from Shelah and Mekler's words that the same holds. Am I missing something or is their assert slightly different from the one you proved? Thank you very much.

Comment: What I wrote is that if the implication holds and $\kappa$ is regular, then indeed $\kappa$ is not the successor of a regular cardinal. This means that either $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible, and then one can proceed to study where such $\kappa$ sit in the large cardinal hierarchy (or at least in the large cardinal hierarchy in $L$, and for the first such $\kappa$) or else $\kappa$ is the successor of a singular cardinal, and then one can proceed to see whether something can be said about the least such $\kappa$, for instance in terms of the cofinality of its predecessor.

Comment: That said, I am not sure what in their paper differs from my description. Let me know what specific statement there seems to suggest something different, and I'll try to double check.